# Strange TS2322 (Type not assignable) Error

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native

I have a super simple code snippet here, but no matter which editor I use (Webstorm, VSCode) I get red underlines under my SearchBar's "onChangeText" property with the following message:

```
TS2322: Type '(val: string) => void' is not assignable to type '((text: string) => void) & ((text: string) => void) & (() => any) & (() => any) & (() => any) & ((text: string) => void) & (() => any) & (() => any) & (() => any)'.   Type '(val: string) => void' is not assignable to type '() => any'.
```

The code is as follows:

```
import React from "react";
import { useState } from "react";
import { StyleSheet, View } from "react-native";
import { SearchBar } from "react-native-elements";
import { KeyboardAwareScrollView } from "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view";
import ScreenWrapper from "../styled/ScreenWrapper";

const HomeScreen = (): JSX.Element => {
  const [searchString, setSearchString] = useState("");

  function updateSearch(val:string):void {
      setSearchString(val)
  }

  return (
    <ScreenWrapper>
      <KeyboardAwareScrollView
        contentContainerStyle={styles.container}
        resetScrollToCoords={{ x: 0, y: 0 }}
        scrollEnabled={false}
      >
        <SearchBar
          placeholder="Type here to search tournaments"
          onChangeText={updateSearch}
          value={searchString}
        />
      </KeyboardAwareScrollView>
    </ScreenWrapper>
  );
};
```

The code seems to compile and execute just fine, but the error in the editor is driving me nuts. Is there a good reason that this is showing?

Comment: Which editor are you using? Have you tried upgrading the ts lib that your editor is using (in VSCode, this would be the `"typescript.tsdk"` setting)? I had a similar problem with something that displayed an error in VSCode but compiled without error, and upgrading the ts lib that VSCode was using resolved it.

Comment: @j1mbl3s thank you for the suggestion. I tried updating the TS version of the project and making sure that my editor was using that same version, but unfortunately the error has not gone away

Comment: Try removing the void return type on the `updateSearch` method.

Comment: @Shivam Just tried that, no luck :(

Thank you for the idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler believes that your `updateSearch` function might be called in a context that expects `() => any`, presumably because of typing on the `onChangeText` attribute. Since your function could be called without any arguments, the compiler thinks it's an error for your function to require any argument. You can fix this by making the `val` argument optional, such as with a reasonable default:

```
function updateSearch(val = ""):void {
    setSearchString(val)
}
```

The [documentation for that attribute](https://reactnativeelements.com/docs/searchbar/#onchangetext) doesn't clarify the arguments it provides, but the typing appears to be correct in [the code itself](https://github.com/react-native-elements/react-native-elements/blob/next/src/searchbar/SearchBar.tsx#L38). Not sure what's going on with the compiler here.

Comment: This worked! Unfortunately, now I'm getting this new issue on the same element. Any idea on this one?

TS2740: Type '{ placeholder: string; onChangeText: (val?: string) => void; value: string; containerStyle: {}; autoCapitalize: "none"; }' is missing the following properties from type 'Pick<TextInputProps & RefAttributes<TextInput> & { platform: "default" | "ios" | "android"; containerStyle?: StyleProp<ViewStyle>; ... 12 more ...; onCancel?(): void; } & ... 6 more ... & Partial<...>, "ref" | ... 138 more ... | "round">': onBlur, onFocus, loadingProps, platform, and 10 more.

Comment: Huh, it wants you to set *every* attribute on the `<SearchBar>`. That's obviously wrong. First I would check that you've got the latest version of `react-native-elements`, in case these typing issues have been fixed already. Beyond that, in my experience, when TypeScript keeps reporting wildly incorrect errors no matter what you change, it's actually getting stuck somewhere else and is so confused that it doesn't know how to tell you. Double-check the other bound attributes, including on `<KeyboardAwareScrollView>`. Then try narrowing it all down further into a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: Great ideas, thank you very much for your help. I'll update if I'm able to track it down!